# Dynamically identifying the action and ajax portion of a UI component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am working on a form that has 4 buttons and each button has a different action and ajax listener. For each of the button there's a javascript method defined 'calljavascriptMethod'. So, the question is when the user clicks any of the button, a corresponding javascript method get`enter code here` executed - I need to know in the javascript method 'calljavascriptMethod' what is the button/component that called this method and what is the corresponding ajax action to be executed??

```
Any idea??
```

ex:

```
<h:commandButton id="YesButton" value="Yes"    action="#myBean.populateItemYes()}">      
    <f:ajax render=":addItemForm" 
        onevent="calljavascriptMethod" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton id="NoButton" value="No" action="#{myBean.populateItemNo()}">
    <f:ajax render=":addItemForm" 
        onevent="calljavascriptMethod" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton id="MaybeButton" value="May be"    action="#myBean.populateItemMayBe()}">     
    <f:ajax render=":addItemForm" 
        onevent="calljavascriptMethod" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton id="LaterButton" value="Later" action="#myBean.populateItemLater()}">    
    <f:ajax render=":addItemForm" 
        onevent="calljavascriptMethod" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsf passes a data object to the onevent javascript function which has the info you need like the source component that triggered the ajax etc., Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkddf.html